# Android emulator running extremely slow on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-2.3, ubuntu-17.04

I know this is a duplicate but i am unable to comment on **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586765/android-emulator-running-extremly-slow-on-ubuntu-17-04-compared-to-windows-10)** thread in order to find out a solution. I have done exactly as the accepted answer but my problem isn't solved. 
I am running Ubuntu 17.04 on a laptop with Intel Core i7 4th Gen Processor, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD and Dual Graphics.
I have installed nVidia Prime drivers and switched to Intel graphics card because it performs better than the nVidia.

I have created a Virtual Device with the following settings:

Device: Google Pixel with API 26

Graphics: Automatic(i have tried both software and hardware btw).

RAM: 4096MB

VM Heap: 1024MB

Internal Storage: 4096MB

Comment: Didn't work as is on that other post for me either, but I think the point is to replace w/e version you have there with the system one. works well after replacing it

Answer (score 1):

First, reduce the RAM of the emulator image to something more reasonable (1024MB, perhaps 1536MB). Do **not** allocate half of your development machine's RAM to an emulator.

Second, confirm that you are using an x86 emulator image (or perhaps x86-64). This shows up in the CPU column of the AVD Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When i first created the emulator it was with the 1536MB of RAM, 256MB VM Heap, 800MB Internal Storage. I am using an x86 emulator image.