# Android Emulator very slow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-20.04

My Android emulator runs very slow on my Ubuntu machine. I need it to run faster, because some apps are slowed down so much, that they change their behaviour (they use the camera).

System specs:

```
-x86_64
-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60 GHz
-20GB Ram
-512Gb HDD
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Android Studio 4.1.1 (fresh installation).
I use this AVD: `Pixel2 1080 x 1920: 420dpi API 28 Android 9.0 (Google X86_ARM) CPU/ABI: x86`
In the extended menu I chose Graphics: `Hardware - GLES 2.0`. I also disabled `GPS, audioInput and audioOutput` with no performance improvements.
I did not try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586765/android-emulator-running-extremly-slow-on-ubuntu-17-04-compared-to-windows-10), because selecting Hardware - GLES 2.0 worked for me and the avd started normally (but still very slow).

Other system images are equally slow though.

I tried:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr 0x3A
```

and it returns `5`, so VT-X is enabled

Is the hardware the bottleneck, or is something configured wrongly? Maybe it is the HDD that slows the emulator down? I tried running the emulator on Windows and it's insanely fast. The windows machine is stronger though.

Update 11.12.2020:
I also verified my KVM installation using this command:

```
./emulator -avd Pixel2Api28Arm -accel-check
```

It returned this:

```
28Arm -accel-check
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable
accel
```

So this does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: Run an ARM image in x86_64 host will cause performance problem. I do not know how 'SLOW' on your computer. But suggest you to try a x86_64 image to check your configuration.

Comment: The image I am using is not an ARM image. It’s a x86 image that contains an ARM translator. Even without running apps that contain ARM code, the emulator is really slow.

Comment: I've got the same problem with Fedora 33, KVM enabled, and so on... It's absolutely not normal and I don't find the problem

Comment: I'm facing the same problem too on Fedora 33.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (KVM working, but slow x64 emulator on x64 host), and found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1742965), which is to disable automatic snapshot creation.

> Run your emulator, and click on the three dots (...) to open the settings:
>
> In the settings, click "Snapshots":
>
> Switch to the "Settings" section on top:
>
> Set "Auto-save current state to Quickboot" to No:
>
> It'll ask you to restart the emulator, click Yes: